# Page breaks in JEditorPane

Tags: html, printing, jtextarea, jeditorpane, page-break

For the love of everything holy, can someone please help me do this?
I have literally been searching for two hours on how to put a page break in a JEditorPane for when it prints to no avail. I've tried everything from HTML styles to even trying sketchy APIs I've found on random websites.

The code I wrote uses a textPaneEditor to print the data, and I use the HTML styling to format it in the way that I need it to look. So, I need a way to add a page break after I push in all of the data for the next line possibly with the HTML styling. Unfortunately, " " doesn't seem to work.

Here's what my code essentially looks like:

```
    String report = "<font size=\"3\">";

    report += "<b> TEST! </b><br>";

    report += "PAGE BREAK WOULD GO HERE<br>";

    report += "</font>";

    JEditorPane textArea = new JEditorPane("text/html", report);

    try{

        textArea.print(new MessageFormat(""), new MessageFormat(""), true, null, null, true);
    }catch(PrinterException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

TLDR; how do I page break a JTextEditorPane with HTML styling during printing to a printer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on solving the same problem myself right now.  One thought I've had is to issue two print commands, one for each page to print.  Not sure if this is or will be the most elegant or efficient solution but it's something to look into.

Comment: I actually solved the problem a while back. I suggest going here:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html and reading all of those.

Comment: You won't be able to solve the problem with a JEditorPane though. You'll need to write the print() function yourself. It's not too hard to implement your own html tags. If you want, I can upload my class and you can use it.